# Updating 14.04 kernel alongside NVIDIA binary driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I'm not that good with the graphics end of things and I try to avoid dealing with proprietary drivers as much as I can. However, after upgrading my graphics card to the 750 Ti, I thought I might as well use the proprietary drivers (nvidia-352) to get the most out of it.

My question is, if I am trying to update my kernel (from 3.13.xx) as per [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). Will I run into issues with the proprietary driver when I install the new xserver stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that I have read in the past that *version* upgrades should be done after removing the proprietary drivers.  Certainly I have seen lots of problems reported by people who had the proprietary drivers enabled when updating.  I think I would put a kernel upgrade into this same category:  Disable the proprietary driver, perform the upgrade, then re-install the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

When the system is set up properly and you follow exactly the instructions :

[Ubuntu 14.04.3 Trusty Tahr Release Notes LTS Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack)

... there should nothing go wrong with the proprietary NVIDIA drivers 352.
After the upgrade you shouldn't notice any different graphics experience.
You don't have to uninstall or reinstall any graphics drivers software at all.

To opt into the Trusty hardware enablement stack - open a terminal and execute this command :

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

If you have Ubuntu (as 64 bit edition) installed in UEFI mode, additionally execute this command :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic-lts-vivid
```

After rebooting the system you are using kernel 3.19 with the NVIDIA drivers remain unchanged.